# In a rootless container how to map a whole range of UDP ports from host to container?

Tags: podman

I am wondering if there is a way to expose a range of UDP ports by mapping them 1:1 from host to container with a rootless container run with Podman.

While the available resources contain information for TCP ports, I haven't been able to find something regarding UDP. Also, `podman port` appears to use namespace "magic" rather than bridges when running rootless.

I want to map a range such as 10000..20000 (UDP) for a host IPv4 address to the container as the same range of ports.

Now with classical VMs one would have `iptables` at one's disposal, but with [slirp4netns](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns) this isn't an option.

How can I achieve it, or is UDP actually impossible and this is a hard limitation of rootless containers?

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this while searching stuff, maybe I can help:

Podman switched the tool for rootless networking to rootlesskit (at least at version >1.8).

with

`-p 35010-35013:35010-35013/udp`

I get

`DEBU[0000] rootlessport: time="2020-05-08T23:05:17Z" level=info msg="exposing ports [{35010 35010 udp } {35011 35011 udp } {35012 35012 udp } {35013 35013 udp }]"`

so it should work.

Also more native network modes like bridge need root to work (to create the network device for the container).